# Hilbert space from the Tate pairing

Tags: elliptic-curves, hilbert-spaces

Fix an elliptic curve $E$ over ${\Bbb Q}$ (or if you prefer, something more general over something more general).  For each extension $F$ of ${\Bbb Q}$, the Néron-Tate height pairing gives
an inner product on $E(F)\otimes {\Bbb R}$.  If one normalizes carefully, all these inner products fit together and give an inner product on  $E(\overline{\Bbb Q})\otimes {\Bbb R}$, where $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ means the algebraic closure.  This real pre-Hilbert space admits a canonical Cauchy closure, so let's write the resulting Hilbert space as $H_E$.  Observe that $H_E$ carries a natural action by isometries of Gal$(\overline{\Bbb Q}/{\Bbb Q})$, so still has intrinsic arithemtic interest.

I have many questions about all this (and will thus feel happy receive your wide-ranging thoughts), but to keep this focused for mathoverflow, I ask: has anyone thought before about these Hilbert spaces associated to elliptic curves, explicitly (probably not) or (perhaps more likely) implicitly?

Comment: Do you mean the height pairing?

Comment: See ch. 5 of P. Fili's PhD thesis: http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/fili/paf-diss.pdf

Comment: @Felipe ...Sorry, yes.

Comment: It might be worth your while to click the "edit" link and change the name of the pairing to something like "Néron-Tate height pairing".  The name "Tate pairing" is now typically used by cryptographers to refer to a map $E[m](k) \times E/E[m](k) \to \mu_m(k)$ for $k$ finite.